# How to find the z-transform of a given quantity?

Tags: stochastic-processes

The arrival of messages to a communications channel is modeled as a Poisson process, with rate $\lambda$ messages / unit time. Let $\{N(t), t \geq 0\}$ denote that process. Each message contains a random number of bytes; the probability mass function of the number of bytes $X_i$ in the $i$th message is given by $G_X(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k z^k$.

Let $Y(t)$ denote the number of bytes which arrived by time $t$.

How should we find the $z$-transform for $Y(t)$ in terms of the known quantities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus, at every time $t\geqslant0$, $Y(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N(t)}X_n$. The invocation of the [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) of the continuous-time process $(Y(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ is rather mysterious here since Z-transforms apply to discrete-time processes.

One can however compute the [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) $g_t$ of each $Y(t)$, that is, the function defined, for (at least) every $|s|\leqslant1$, by 
$g_t(s)=\mathrm E\left(s^{Y(t)}\right)$. 
First note that, for every $k\geqslant0$,
$$
\mathrm E\left(s^{Y(t)}\mid N(t)=k\right)=G_X(s)^k,
$$
and that $N(t)$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda t$, hence
$$
g_t(s)=\sum_{k\geqslant0}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}G_X(s)^k=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t(1-G_X(s))}.
$$

Comment: If Z-transforms are really what you are after, you might wish to recall the definition of the notion you have in mind.